# How to Join a Table2 and keeping the entry from Table1 as Null

Tags: sql, join

Lets say I have 2 tables.

Table 1:

```
Columns:  Account Transaction 
Rows:     1234    1
          1234    2
          1234    3
          1234    4
```

Table 2: (Transaction 1 is not on this table)

```
Columns:  Dispute Transaction 
Rows:     Yes     2
          Yes     3
          Yes     4
```

I would basically like all the transactions from Table 1, and if they don't exist on Table 2, I would like it to stay as NULL instead of removing that entry.

```
**SELECT**  
T1.Account  
,T1.Transaction  
,T2.Dispute  
**FROM** Table1 **AS** T1  
**JOIN** Table2 AS T2 **ON** T1.Transaction = T2.Transaction
```

The end result I would like is: (Include Transaction 1 as a NULL entry for Dispute Column)

```
Columns:  Account Transaction Dispute
Rows:     1234    1           NULL
          1234    2           Yes
          1234    3           Yes
          1234    4           Yes
```

But when I use JOIN, I get:

```
Columns:  Account Transaction Dispute
Rows:     1234    2           Yes
          1234    3           Yes
          1234    4           Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a LEFT JOIN.  That will give you everything from Table 1 and return NULLS for those that don't exist in Table 2.